# Phrase to describe a potential positive future for a person?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I am describing a person whose recent performance has been excellent and whose future has potential.

What expression can be used other than "future looks potential" or "has a bright future"? It should be used to give an idea of an optimistic impression of the person's future.

Comment: "… has a bright future ahead" is a very good and common expression. Can you explain why it doesn't satisfy you? Do you want to avoid cliches? Or do you want an alternative synonym phrase? Or do you want a single word? (You had the SWR tag)

Comment: Just the word "potential" is needed. Look up the word in a good dictionary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I have overused the expression "... has a bright future ahead " in my writing and wish to find similar alternatives to this expression or a single word that could represent the idea.

Comment: You should edit, and clarify. The more relevant detail, the better :)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, terms like 'has potential' often fall on cynical ears. Unless you are very specific, and give reasons why a person has potential and examples, this type of comment is best described as puffery:
[Definition and examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffery)

Nevertheless, here are some alternative phrases:

- 'has proven skills worth developing'
- 'could soon achieve excellence'
- 'deserves recognition for their achievements'
- 'has enviable proficiency'
- 'has risen admirably to recent challenges'
- 'urgently needs a pay-rise, a company car and a slice of cake' [Please ensure you have the power to supply items promised as rewards.]

Comment: "urgently needs a pay-rise, a company car and a slice of cake" I'll take *that*!

Answer (score 1):

> [Name] has [**a promising career**](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=2P1jW-HKJo7nsAe_obrwCA&q=%22promising%20career%20in%22&oq=%22promising%20career%20in%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30k1l4j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l2.5804.30224.0.31893.10.10.0.0.0.0.241.1557.0j7j3.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.1554...0i7i30k1j0i67k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.XV8LQ0KhQyU)/**future** in [software engineering]

promising career = likely to be successful ([LDCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/career))

NB. The OP should avoid saying that someone's *future looks potential*, it is not idiomatic or grammatical.

Google produces only [six results](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=BghkW_ejDsO6kwW57oDwCA&q=%22future%20looks%20potential%22&oq=%22future%20looks%20potential%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...572306.574495.0.574784.2.2.0.0.0.0.288.446.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Cj4kTfWnGKk) for this phrase, two of which come from the OP's question. Instead, it is more idiomatic to say that someone's future “**shows great potential**” or “**looks promising**”